# Hover images(Enlarge image on Mouse Hover) from SharePoint list 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, development

We had SharePoint list with image column. Our request, when some one keep mouse on image column, picture need to enlarge(hover). Can someone suggest direct how to achieve with code. Thanks in advance

Note: Images exist on list not on Page and SP2013 Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to enlarge images on hover.

CSS to enlarge images on hover for your reference:

https://success.figure-eight.com/hc/en-us/articles/202703155-CSS-Guide-to-Enlarge-Images-on-Hover

Besides, similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0c56070f-d20c-44fb-bd4b-d7e2d18c9157/image-hover-in-sharepoint-images?forum=sharepointdevelopment

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/get-pictures-from-sharepoint-picture-library-and-enlarge-on/

Comment: Lisa, i tried the links which you have shared, unfortunately its not helped. I need hover image option on SharePoint list not on SharePoint page. Could you please help on this. Note: Hover images(Enlarge image on Mouse Hover) on the the SharePoint list 2013